# Applying effect to meshView JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, shader

I'm trying to adjust the color but this only seems to be working on an ImageView. Is there a reason for it not to work on a MeshView?

```
Material material = new PhongMaterial(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
meshView.setMaterial(material);

ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
colorAdjust.setContrast(0.5);
colorAdjust.setHue(-0.55);
colorAdjust.setBrightness(0.2);
colorAdjust.setSaturation(0.2);

meshView.setEffect(colorAdjust);
```